# Navbar position

Tags: css, web

I am currently working on building my photography portfolio site.
I try to position my navbar under my logo, but I can't match the navbar to the size and the postion of the logo.

any idea how can I position my  nav using CSS?

[image: See attached photo]

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, none can help you if you dont add more information and data.

Comment: please provide the source code so we can help you out in your problem

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix. Hero is de [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo,
nav {
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```